# Suggestions to clean duct tape(?) from interior

Tags: cleaning, interior

I recently purchased a GTI mk4 and it needs a little fixing up but it runs great. 
However, I would like to clean up duct tape residue but could possibly be other things as well from the interior of the car. (Please view attached picture).
I appreciate your help!
Thanks.[image: GTI Interior with residue]

Comment: Idk where you live but there’s this stuff called goo-gone try that maybe if nobody else has ideas

Comment: That's going to be tough, because a lot of the things I could think to try would probably also warp and damage the plastic of the dash.  +1 and hoping someone has some input.

Comment: Thanks. @JPhi1618 for the reply. I’m in Los Angeles. I just picked up some isopropyl 91% hoping it will work. I’ll try it out first in a place that you can’t really see. If it doesn’t clean it or it does but ruins the dash, do you know of ways to cover the dash?

Comment: I have used WD40 in the past - it does not tend to damage the plastic...

Comment: that looks to me like a big crack in the dash that was taped over.

Comment: @agentp I con confirm it’s not a crack.

Comment: well I'll second the goo-gone,or a similar product called goof off, or acetone.  Whatever you try test on a small inconspicuous spot first to be sure it doesn't take the color out of the vinyl.